# Proving a minimum vertex cover for a family of 3-uniform hypergraphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $H_n$ be a $3$-uniform hypergraph. For every $\{a, b, c\} \subseteq [n]$ we have an edge $\{\{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{b, c\}\} \in H_n$.

> What is the minimum vertex cover of $H_n$?

The following construction is a vertex cover of $H_n$ (call it $C_n$), but I am not sure how to prove it is a minimum vertex cover (and it may not be a minimum).

Let $Sub_k(S) = \{A \subseteq S \mid |A| = k\}$ (does this have a standard notation?) and partition $[n]$ into two disjoint sets $L_n$ of the odd elements and $R_n$ of the even elements. Then,

$$C_n = Sub_2(L_n) \cup Sub_2(R_n)$$

This is indeed a vertex cover, since for any edge $\{\{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{b, c\}\}$ we have,

- $a, b$ are both odd, then $\{a, b\} \subseteq L_n$
- $a, b$ are both even, then $\{a, b\} \subseteq R_n$

Otherwise assume $a$ is odd and $b$ is even, then either,

- $c$ is odd and $\{a, c\} \subseteq L_n$
- $c$ is even and $\{b, c\} \subseteq R_n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commonly used notations for the set of all $k$-element subsets of a set $S$ are $[S]^k$ and $\binom S k$.

Your construction is indeed the (essentially unique) minimum vertex cover of your $H_n$. To put it in terms of ordinary graphs ($2$-uniform hypergraphs), you're looking for the smallest subgraph $G$ of $K_n$ which contains at least one edge of every triangle in $K_n$. In other words, you want the complementary graph $\overline G$ to be a triangle-free graph on $n$ vertices with the **maximum** possible number of edges. This is answered by Mantel's theorem, which is a special case of Turán's theorem: the answer is $\overline G=K_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor,\lceil n/2\rceil}$, a complete bipartite graph with $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$ edges.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem